# How to alter an item in an object using JavaScript to replace special characters that are not accepted by Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push some Kubernetes stats to my Firebase Real-time Database (not Firestore) and due to the special character "/" in the keys, Firebase is throwing an error. I tried to search for similar issues here but they are not quite similar to mine (tried so many replace or even delete functions but did not work). Here are my objects:

=====>> [THE OBJECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBEKk.png)

So i want to change the "/" to something like "-" on order to be able to push the entire object as to Firebase.

Example:

```
beta.kubernetes.io/arch --> beta.kubernetes.io-arch
beta.kubernetes.io/os --> beta.kubernetes.io-os
kubernetes.io/hostname --> kubernetes.io-hostname
node-role.kubernetes.io/master --> node-role.kubernetes.io-master
```

Please note that i have to process this in the attached object screenshot. So i have to process this: **k8snodes{obj}** -> **items[arr]** -> **metadata{obj}** -> **labels{obj}** in order to reach the **keys** i want to replace, and then push the entire object (k8snodes) to firebase.

I am using Javascript/NodeJS. thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried [.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) fucntion?

Comment: yes, but did not work.. i need the full JavaScript code please. How to iterate over the array/object to do so? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it according to your data structure.

`.reduce()` reference: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var k8snodes = {
 items: [
   {
     "metadata": {
       "labels": {
         "beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd",
                "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux"
        }
      }
    },
    {
     "metadata": {
       "labels": {
         "kubernetes.io/hostname": "centos-master-node",
                "node-role.kubernetes.io/master": "master"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}



   k8snodes.items.forEach(function(data){
 var newK8snodes = Object.keys(data.metadata.labels).reduce((total,currentValue) => {
            var newLabelKey = currentValue.replace(/\//g,'-')
       var newLabel = {[newLabelKey]: data.metadata.labels[currentValue]}     
   
            total = {...total, ...newLabel}      
            return total;
          }, {});  
  
      data.metadata.labels = newK8snodes

    });
console.log(k8snodes);
```

Comment: thanks Alvin, that's assuming i have a single string. In my case, it is a complex object. How can i loop through to replace that specific child object to replace each item? thanks.

Comment: @Honshu Code updated according to your data structure

Comment: Awesome!! thanks @Alvin works great for me. Just one more question if you don't mind, how can i relace multiple special chars in the same code above? Firebase doesn't accept ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" .. so in my example above, your code indeed replaces the "/" but i need it also to replace the "." .. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

another simple solution is

```js
var a = 'beta.kubernetes.io/arch';
console.log(a.replace('/','-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const ob = {
  'beta.kubernetes.io/arch': 'amd',
  'beta.kubernetes.io/os': 'linux',
  'kubernetes.io/hostname': 'centos',
  'node-role.kubernetes.io/master': 'master'
}
const newOb = {};

for(var i in ob) {
  const newKey = i.replace(/\//g,'-')
  newOb[newKey] = ob[i];
}

console.log(newOb);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, i think i am so close. The issue here again is that you have ob as a simple object, while in my case, it is a complex object (in the attached screenshot). So i have to process this: k8snodes{obj} -> items[arr] -> metadata{obj} -> labels{obj} in order to reach the keys i want to replace, and then push the entire object (k8snodes) to firebase. thanks.